# URIError: Failed to decode param '/%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico' at decodeURIComponent () at decode_param

Tags: reactjs, macos

URIError: Failed to decode param '/%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico'

```
at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
at decode_param (/Users/anwarsagor/Desktop/programmingHero/ph-projects/your-warehouse/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:172:12)
at Layer.match (/Users/anwarsagor/Desktop/programmingHero/ph-projects/your-warehouse/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:123:27)
at matchLayer (/Users/anwarsagor/Desktop/programmingHero/ph-projects/your-warehouse/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:585:18)
at next (/Users/anwarsagor/Desktop/programmingHero/ph-projects/your-warehouse/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:226:15)
at expressInit (/Users/anwarsagor/Desktop/programmingHero/ph-projects/your-warehouse/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/anwarsagor/Desktop/programmingHero/ph-projects/your-warehouse/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/Users/anwarsagor/Desktop/programmingHero/ph-projects/your-warehouse/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:328:13)
at /Users/anwarsagor/Desktop/programmingHero/ph-projects/your-warehouse/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:286:9
at Function.process_params (/Users/anwarsagor/Desktop/programmingHero/ph-projects/your-warehouse/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
```

Screenshot of code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T3n5.png

Comment: That string was apparently used as the path part of a URL sent to your app, but it is invalid. _In Windows CMD and 'start'_ `%name%` is used to substitute an environment variable; if the client program issuing this request was run on Windows, you or someone might have intended this to be substituted with a value that is valid for a URL, but it wasn't, perhaps because you weren't on CMD or used the wrong envvar name or didn't set the envvar correctly (e.g. in the correct scope). Or possibly it was run on non-Windows by someone who mistakenly used the Windows syntax.